# Use foreign key as variable in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am new to Django and Python (and even newish to programming) and am now creating my first application.  I have a model that includes a foreign key, which is a many-to-one relation (a line can hold many articles, but every article only relates to one line).  In my template I want to concatenate a number of values to create an url for an image source.

relevant information in models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
  line = models.ForeignKey(Line, null=True)
  article = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  slug = models.SlugField(null=True)

class Line(models.Model):
  line = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```

The relevant view sends `Article.objects.get(slug=article_slug)` as `article` in `context_dict` to the template.  In my template I include the following and returns the expected values correctly: `{{ article.article }}` and `{{ article.line }}`.  If I concatenate the value of `article.article` it returns the expected value:

```
{% with article.article as a %}
```

Here `{{ a }}` shows the value of article.article.  However when I try concatenate the value of `article.line`, I get no value.

```
{% with article.line as l %}
```

`{{ l }}` doesn't return anything.  I assume this is because the foreign key can also be interpreted as one-to-many and so I tried to specify which value (I also used variations such as `article.line.all.0`).

```
{% with article.line_set|first as l %}
```

Here `{{ l }}` also doesn't return anything.

Why can I return the value of `article.line` as text in the template, but I can't include it in a concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`article.line_set` is not the correct way of printing related `Line` objects as there is no such relation between them.

As for the problem, it is very likely that 
`article.line` is `None` and I think Django template engine is silently suppressing possible `Models.DoesNotExist` exception when trying to access `.line` property of the `article.line` instance which is null.

Make sure `article.line` is not `None` so that you can print out the text representation of it as follows:

```
{% with article.line.line as l %}
```

Comment: Thank you: `article.line.line` was the solution!  As to the database design, I am not sure your suggestion is correct: in my database I can have article A belonging to line X and article B also belonging to line X, A and B cannot belong to any other line.  To continue, article K, L and M can belong to line Y, but not to any other line.